# Link multiple fileupload with checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, checkbox

I want to link multiple fileuploads with checkboxes in php.

this is what i have:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1"> linked to file-upload 1 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1"> linked to file-upload 2 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2"> linked to file-upload 3 <br/>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3"> linked to file-upload 4 <br/>
```

I want to do something when a file is uploaded and the related checkbox is checked in PHP,
how do i link the file input type with the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine them under one name array.

```
<input type='file' name='combined[1][file]'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='combined[1][check]'/>
```

Which can be accessed in php with:

`$_REQUEST['combined'][1]['file']`

Answer (score 0):

assign same names to the upload elements and checkbox as an array

```
<input type='file' name="element_one" />
<input type=checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='element_one'/>
//then is the submitted script you might have 
$checkboxes = $_POST['checkbox'];
if(in_array('element_one',$checkboxes)){

   //elementone checkbox was selected so expect that some has been uploaded through  element_one file input box
}
```